# Add a view to CollectionView header in StoryBoard

Tags: ios, swift, collections, view, header

I have 2 views on top of my CollectionView and just want to scroll on all these 3 views. I understand the best approach is to place these 2 top views in my collectionView header. How can I achieve this in storyboard (interface builder) without any code?
(I use this way in my another tableView but I have can't do this with CollectionoView)

I drag those 2 views to my collectionView's reusableView(headerView) and I've faced with this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjzrr.png)

Comment: I recommend you to use scroll view in the bottom and setting views and collection view on top of it. Which actually gives better results for you in future

Comment: Apple deprecate this solution because two scrolls overlap and even if I disable collectionView's scrolling property another problem is I haven't exact height of my contentView (CollectionView's height is dynamic) to say to my scrollView and this will cause error in IB @SivajeeBattina

Comment: No, you can find out collection view's height. use collectionView.ContentSize property to get its height.

Comment: I should set secrollView's contentView's size in storyboard and in IB I can not set CollectionView's height dynamically.

Comment: You can set scrollView Content height once collection view loading completes right?

Comment: the contents are loading from a server and are dynamic. I don't know how set the height of my content view(you know, scroll view should exactly know about its size)

Comment: I understood. I had done that. It's possible. I'm just giving that direction bro ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can drag and drop in interface builder and get header view for collection view. You have to additionally implement viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind method which returns UICollectionReusableView. While using collection reusable view, we have to treat that view in different way similar to stuffs we do for reusable cell.

Steps to follow.

1. Create a class (HeaderViewExample) for that header view.
2. Assign class (HeaderViewExample) to the reusable view you have just added  in interface builder.
3. Give a reusable identifier (HeaderViewExample) to that reusable view.
4. Now you add label or buttons to the reusable view and create outlets for those outlets in the Class **HeaderViewExample**.

(**Note: While using reusable views, don't create outlets directly in the controller.**)

Now Update your CollectionViewController with the below code.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: 
NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    var reusableView = UICollectionReusableView()

    if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
          guard let view = collectionView?.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: String(HeaderViewExample), forIndexPath: indexPath) as? HeaderViewExample else { return reusableView }
          view.label = "Test String"
          view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    } else {
      assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }

    return reusableView
  }
```

Comment: I do this but I get another error wich said : "~/Main.storyboard: error: Illegal Configuration: The liveCarousel outlet from the LiveViewController to the iCarousel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content." How I should connect my view's outlet to the main viewController?