# Setup Header Cell UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I created collectionView as below:

[image]

I would like to create a collection view as same as this layout, with one biggest header cell like the one with red iPhone7. Now I wonder which approach is better, to create an extra cell or handle this in `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`?. My data is an array which fetched from JSON, so i would like to make the big cell is the first item.

Honestly, I see that second approach is quite complicated.

So can anyone help me to find best solution for this. 
Thank you so much for reading this and have a nice day ahead.

Comment: Create two sections in collection view , for section one with that large width

Comment: Do you need header anchor to top when scrolling ?

Comment: My data is an array which fetched from JSON, so i would like to make the big cell is the first item.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to attribute inspector of `UIColectionView`.
2. From Accessories select Section Header
3. Once header view is visible , add your views to it.

Then in following method tweak accordingly:

```
  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView ,viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String,at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader{
      return headerView
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check this one out as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365238/add-a-view-to-collectionview-header-in-storyboard/43365352#43365352